# Como posso usar os resultados de uma função dentro de outra em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde, eu estou estudando python sozinho e estou tentando fazer um pequeno programinha com listas e funções, o programa ele vai receber 10 nomes e armazar em uma lista, depois 10 notas e armazenar em outra lista, até aí tudo bem, o problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer com que eu pegue o resultado das funções, ou seja, as listas e utilizar uma funçao "final" para mostar na tela.

O que acontece é que quando eu termino de executar a ultima função o programa encerra e não retorna nada. Segue o código:

```
def preencher_nome(): #função para o usuario preencher uma lista com 10 nomes
lista = []
contador = len(lista)
while contador <= 9:
    lista.append(str(input("Digite o nome do aluno ")))
    contador = contador + 1
n = int(input("\nAgora você terminou de preencher os nomes, digite 2 para preencher as notas\n"))
if n == 2:
    preencher_notas()
return lista

def preencher_notas(): #função para o usuario preencher uma lista com 10 notas
    print("Agora você poderá preencher as notas\n")
    print("\n\n")
    notas = []
    count = len(notas)
    while count <= 9:
        notas.append(int(input("Digite a nota dos alunos obedecendo a sequencia dos nomes")))
        count = count + 1
    return notas
def main():
    print("Olá\n")
    x = int(input("Digite 1 para começar a preencher o nome dos estudantes\n"))
    if x == 1:
        preencher_nome()
    else:
        print("Opção Inválida")




main()
```

Comment: Precisa fazer algo como `nomes = preencher_nome()`. Aconselho você a estudar algoritmos antes de estudar uma linguagem de programação. A aprendizagem em algoritmos tende a ser mais fácil do que aprender esses conceitos básicos direto na linguagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu algorítimo python possue alguns erros de lógica. começando pela função *preencher_nome()*:

```
def preencher_nome(): 
lista = []
contador = len(lista)
while contador <= 9:
    lista.append(str(input("Digite o nome do aluno ")))
    contador = contador + 1
    n = int(input("\nAgora você terminou de preencher os nomes, digite 2 para preencher as notas\n"))
    if n == 2: 
        preencher_notas()
    return lista
```

Ao testar a condicional 'if n == 2' você oferece apenas uma opção, o que acaba forçando a saída do loop caso digite algo diferente de '2' e por consequencia o cadastro de apenas um aluno na lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O certo a se fazer seria:

```
def preencher_nome(): #função para o usuario preencher uma lista com 10 nomes
lista = []
contador = len(lista)
while contador <= 9:
    lista.append(str(input("Digite o nome do aluno ")))
    contador = contador + 1

print ('Você cadastrou o numero total de alunos, em seguida preencha as notas.')
preencher_notas()
return lista
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma vez que você já tem um delimitador em seu laço while para entrada de 10 nomes.

Tendo isso em mente vamos ao seu problema.
O motivo pelo qual voce nao consegue usar o valor das listas é porque as mesmas são criadas **DENTRO** da função. Dessa forma ela *existe*, por assim dizer, somente em quanto a função esta rodando. 
O certo a se fazer é declarar as listas fora das funções para que sejam *'elementos'* globais de seu código e *depois* passalas para sua função:

```
nomes = []
notas = []

def preencher_nome(lista): #Passe sua lista para a função
contador = len(lista)
while contador <= 9:
    nomes.append(str(input("Digite o nome do aluno ")))
    contador = contador + 1

print ('Você cadastrou o numero total de alunos, em seguida preencha as notas.')
preencher_notas(notas) #Quando chamar sua função não esqueça de passar a lista como argumento
return lista

def preencher_notas(notas): #função para o usuario preencher uma lista com 10 notas
print("Agora você poderá preencher as notas\n")
print("\n\n")
count = len(notas)
while count <= 9:
    notas.append(int(input("Digite a nota dos alunos obedecendo a sequencia dos nomes")))
    count = count + 1
return notas

def main():
    print("Olá\n")
    x = int(input("Digite 1 para começar a preencher o nome dos estudantes\n"))
    if x == 1:
        preencher_nome(nomes)
    else:
        print("Opção Inválida")


log = main()

print (nomes)
print (notas)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS** : Ao contrário do que muitos dizem, não é errado começar a aprender a programar direto em uma linguagem de programação. Python é ótima para isso e eu te aconselho a seguir mesmo esse caminho. Mas a medida que progride e precisa fazer programas mais complexos, conhecimentos diferentes vão sendo requisitados de voce. Então leia também sobre Algorítimos, Banco de dados, Estrutura de dados etc... Assim você se torna um programador mais completo.

Espero ter te ajudado.
Segue uma [recomendação](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/index.html) de livro que me ajudou muito no inicio.
Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Você não vê nada porque não deu print.  Tudo que você deseja ver no terminal precisa ser printado. A sua funcão retorna a lista, porém não printa. Por isso você não vê nada. Sugestão: Dentro do seu `if n == 1` substitua a linha `preencher_notas()` por `print preencher_notas()`.

> Obs: Não sei se você deseja executar o que está na primeira funcão também, mas se quiser precisa chamá-la também.